# How is this overflow 'trick' achieved?

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

I am relatively new to coding and for practice I'm recreating the design of other websites. I have no idea how the box called 'quick-start instructions' (it's above the cat, kind of) is placed. 
https://jekyllrb.com/
Specifically, what I'm asking is how to make an element overflow both below AND above the its parent. I couldn't find out from inspecting the element (if someone knows how to find it out by inspecting the element that would be even more helpful!), but right now the only solution that I think would work is using absolute positioning, which seems to be extremely cumbersome and timeconsuming.
Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, I want to do this with html and css

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track inspecting the element. This was accomplished using negative margin values. If you kept digging, you would have seen this code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.quickstart .code {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: -30px 0;
    float: right;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may understand the overflow concept after see this example link.

```
<div class="container">
   <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like.</span>
</div>
```

working link in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/f1fctm1f/)

Hope it would helpful to you.
Cool!

Comment: Note: This is an example of overflow:visible only in vertical direction that means top and bottom sides of the parent. As the same way we can do for the remaining sides as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have this element:

```
   <div class="unit golden-large code">
      <p class="title">Quick-start Instructions</p>
      <div class="shell">
        <p class="line">
          ...
        </p>
        <p class="line">
         ...
        </p>
        <p class="line">
          ...
        </p>
        <p class="line">
          ...
        </p>
        <p class="line">
          ...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this style:

```
.quickstart .code {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: -30px 0;
  float: right;
}
```

The height of the element is set by the content (it's higher than his container) and the negative margin allow you to put an element outter of his container.